# Are there any integral domains in which irreducible elements are easily identified?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

In every integral domain I've studied so far irreducible elements have been impossible to quickly identify in general with any known procedure. Is there an integral domain for which such a procedure exists?

Comment: How about the integers?

Comment: That is not efficient in general, though. Once the primes get very large it becomes impossible.

Comment: Not at all impossible. It can be tested in polynomial time which is about as effective as you could hope. Are you looking for something that could be done in constant time?

Comment: Ah, I actually didn't know that. Polynomial time was what I was looking for. Thanks for letting me know.